# How to host my web app on heroku with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, heroku

As far as I know, while deploying your web application on Heroku (from github) you need to provide a requirement.txt file so that every library which is used can be installed. But you cannot install MySQL like that. I've used python and streamlit to create a web application. I used MySQL to store data. I don't want the local machine's data to be exported but want to store the data when it is deployed as web app and someone fill in the details (it's basically a Student DBMS).

How can I deploy such a web application that uses MySQL on heroku ?

I've read some docs and look around and found that PostgreSQL is more suitable but I want to use MySQL because this is school project.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a add-ons called ClearDB for Mysql

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb